# How to fix clickable background with Wordpress theme and CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, background, ads

I have a problem using a clickable adverting skin as background of my Wordpress site. My site is this: http://www.tvindiretta.com. If you scroll down any page of my site you will see that the top of the background covers the content and mess all up... I think that I should add a white background in foreground. I really need your help, I'm a noob in CSS and programming.... I read about this parameters googling for...

```
display: block; ??
text-indent: px; ??
overflow: hidden; ??
z-index:22 ???
```

...but I don't know how to solve this problem... Here is my Wordpress theme CSS file http://www.tvindiretta.com/wp-content/themes/videoplus/style.css Thanks a LOT for any help in advance

P.S. This site: IMPRONTALAQUILA.ORG in certain pages shows the same ad and also other similar skins without any bug or problem... how can I get the same result? I want the background to be fixed so that users see it browsing any part of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `fixed` from

```
background: white url(http://www.affiliago.it/accounts/default1/banners/SKIN_BAKECA.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
```

In your `body` style.

UPDATE:

Add in your css:

```
.myClass{
    background-color:white;
    width:994px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

And add those styles to:

`<div class="clear">` to `<div class="clear myClass">`

`<nav>` to `<nav class="myClass">`

`<div class="wrap">` to `<div class="wrap myClass">`

Comment: It solves the problem but I want the background to be fixed so that users see it browsing any part of the page, other solutions?

Comment: Then put the middle section in a div and make that div scrolleble.[Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/overflow)

Comment: Sorry but I'm a noob in coding. What code i should insert and where exactly?

Comment: You are my hero!!! Thank you SOO MUCH!!! Today I will edit my site. Sorry for late reply but yesterday  evening  I wasn't at the PC.

Comment: I tried to edit css and php code but I have gone wrong with something. This is the result: http://www.tvindiretta.com . Could you tell me where I made the mistake and help me to correct? Thank you :)

Comment: There is no more left and right padding between elements also in the post sidebar ( for ex. http://www.tvindiretta.com/rai-due-estero-alternativa/ ) and there is a large border on the right side.